# reorganizing a file in a special way [Perl]

Tags: perl

Consider the following file:

```
5,*,ABC
6,5,XYZ
7,5,123
4,6,xyz
1,4,xox
8,6,yoy
```

The format of each line: (`*` has no parent)

```
pid,parent-pid,name
```

I would like to somehow to create the following file:

```
ABC,
ABC,XYZ
ABC,123
ABC,XYZ,xyz
ABC,XYZ,xyz,xyx
ABC,XYZ,yoy
```

Meaning for every PID, I can go to its greatest parent on the same line.
I thought to implement it (in Perl) with hash by inserting it into a hash. problem is I don't really know what would be the length of each line and then the length of the hash.
Also, I'm looking for the most efficient way possible.

What good algorithm would solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You could build a hash of pids keyed by parent pid.

```
use feature qw( current_sub );

use Text::CSV_XS qw( );

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 2 });

my %process_children_by_pid;
my %process_name_by_pid;
while (my $row = $csv->getline(*STDIN)) {
   my ($pid, $parent, $name) = @$row;
   $process_name_by_pid{$pid} = $name;
   push @{ $processes_children_by_pid{$parent} }, $pid;
}

sub {
   my $pid = pop;
   push @_, $process_name_by_pid{$pid};
   $csv->say(*STDOUT, \@_);
   __SUB__->(@_, $_) for @{ $processes_children_by_pid{$pid} };
}->($_) for @{ $processes_children_by_pid{'*'} };
```

Or you could use Graph.pm. This has more overhead, but it makes error checking easy.

```
use feature qw( current_sub );

use Graph        qw( );
use Text::CSV_XS qw( );

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 2 });

my $tree = Graph->new();
my %process_name_by_pid;
while (my $row = $csv->getline(*STDIN)) {
   my ($pid, $parent, $name) = @$row;
   $process_name_by_pid{$pid} = $name;
   $tree->add_edge($parent, $pid);
}

die "Bad data" if $tree->has_a_cycle;

my @roots = $tree->predecessorless_vertices();
die "Bad data" if @roots != 1 || $roots[0] ne '*';

sub {
   my $pid = pop;
   push @_, $process_name_by_pid{$pid};
   $csv->say(*STDOUT, \@_);
   __SUB__->(@_, $_) for $tree->successors($pid);
}->($_) for $tree->successors('*');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would handle it by storing an array of the parent relationships and then traversing through that array each time a line was read:

```
my @parent;

open my $IN, '<', 'file' or die;
while (<$IN>) {
  chomp;
  my ($id, $parent, $name) = split /,/;
  $parent[$id] = [ $parent, $name ];

  if ($parent eq '*') {
    print $name;
  } else {
    my @output = ( [ $parent, $name ] );

    while (my $p = $parent[${$output[0]}[0]]) {
      unshift @output, $p;
    }

    print join ',', map { ${$_}[1] } @output;
  }

  print "\n";
}
close $IN;
```

Output:

```
ABC
ABC,XYZ
ABC,123
ABC,XYZ,xyz
ABC,XYZ,xyz,xox
ABC,XYZ,yoy
```

-- EDIT -- Per feedback, revised to use hashes and not be dependent on file order:

```
my %parent;

open my $IN, '<', 'file' or die;
while (<$IN>) {
  chomp;
  my ($id, $parent, $name) = split /,/;
  $parent{$id} = [ $parent, $name ];
}

seek $IN, 0, 0;
while (<$IN>) {
  chomp;
  my ($id, $parent, $name) = split /,/;

  if ($parent eq '*') {
    print $name;
  } else {
    my @output = ( [ $parent, $name ] );

    while (my $p = $parent{${$output[0]}[0]}) {
      unshift @output, $p;
    }

    print join ',', map { ${$_}[1] } @output;
  }

  print "\n";
}
close $IN;
```

Comment: PIDs are 16-bit numbers, if not larger. Using a hash would be better than an array. /// This mis-parses and mis-generates CSV. Use a module; it's just two extra lines. /// This approach makes 15 process name lookups for the sample data, whereas mine only does 6. /// This version assumes the children always come after their parents in the input. That's an unsafe assumption since the format is suggestive of a database table. /// All those limitations for what?

Comment: For deep trees, it would be faster to using `push` then `reverse` instead of `unshift`. `unshift` is optimized, but still leads to multiple whole-array copies in that situation. (For shallow trees, it probably doesn't matter either way)

Comment: @Hambone, I really like your solution. One problem is that your solution is depended on the that the main parent line location (meaning it should be at the first line when it should not always be like this). For example fo `6,5,XYZ \n 5,*,ABC` it won't give the expected output. Is it possible to insert the data into a hash or an array instead of printing?

Comment: Your feedback is appropriate and consistent with ikegami's.  Perl is obviously not my core competency -- I love it and use it in my work, but I am far from an expert and would defer to experts like ikegami on best practices.  I did edit the solution to use a hash instead of an array, and it's no longer dependent on file order -- although the solution was to "rewind" the file to the beginning.  It still suffers from multiple lookups for the same items, as pointed out.

Comment: Also, you could certainly loop through the results via an array/hash instead of printing...  can you clarify specifically how you would want that done?